# Entity Framework 6.1.1 DbJoinExpression get all left columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I am trying to get an expression tree visitor to add a join to another table when certain entities are queried.  The expression works great if I include a `.Select()` method with projection into an anonymous type and directly specify the columns for the particular entity being queried:

```
var joinEntity = expression.Target.EntityContainer.BaseEntitySets.Single(s => s.Name == "TestJoinTable");

return expression.InnerJoin(
    DbExpressionBuilder.Scan(joinEntity),
        (l, r) => DbExpressionBuilder.And(
                DbExpressionBuilder.Equal(
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Property(l, "JoinId"),
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Property(r, "JoinId")
                )
                , DbExpressionBuilder.Equal(
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Property(r, "UserId"),
                    DbExpression.FromInt32(_userId)
                )
            )
        )
    .Select(exp =>
        new { // these are the 3 columns from one specific entity I have called Resources
                ResourceId = exp.Property("l").Property("ResourceId"),
                ResourceName = exp.Property("l").Property("ResourceName"),
                JoinId = exp.Property("l").Property("JoinId"),
            }
    );
```

The LINQ to Enties query that is causing this expression logic to run in this particular case is:

```
List<Resource> resources = db.Resources.ToList();
```

The problem is, the expression visitor code is intended to run against many different entity queries, not just the Resource entity query.  I need a dynamic way to select all columns from the left entity.  I need to specify something like:

```
.Select( exp => exp.Property("l").Property("*") )
```

The above expression doesn't compile.  It throws the error: `No property with the name '*' is declared by the type 'ScratchDbModel.Store.Resource'`.

I also tried this, but it fails with a similar error message:

```
.Select( exp => exp.Property("l.*") )
```

I tried selecting just the left entity like this:

```
.Select( exp => exp.Property("l") )
```

The above expression compiles and looks promising right up until the point that it actually runs the query, which reults in this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ResourceId] AS [ResourceId], 
    [Extent1].[ResourceName] AS [ResourceName], 
    [Extent1].[JoinId] AS [JoinId]
    FROM ( SELECT [l]
        FROM  [dbo].[Resource] AS [l]
        INNER JOIN [sec].[TestJoinTable] AS [r]
    ON ([l].[JoinId] = [r].[JoinId]) AND ([r].[UserId] = 2)
    )  AS [Extent1]
```

And since the inner SELECT is selecting `[l]` and not `[l.*]` or the list of column names, query execution fails with this message:

```
Invalid column name 'l'.
Invalid column name 'ResourceId'.
Invalid column name 'ResourceName'.
Invalid column name 'JoinId'.
```

I have tried many different things but can't seem to figure out how to do this.  If I leave off the `.Select()` entirely, I receive the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No property with the name 'ResourceId' is declared by the type 'Transient.rowtype[(l,ScratchDbModel.Store.Resource(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)),(r,ScratchDbModel.Store.TestJoinTable(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=))]'.
```

Of course, this is because the Entity Framework is expecting to receive `IEnumerable<Resource>`, not some multi-table join result.

Is there any way to either generically specify "all columns from the left table" or to create some type of dynamic anonymous type or dynamic projection containing all column references for the left entity?

Answer (score 1):

To select all properties of property l just select it whole:

```
return expression.InnerJoin(
    DbExpressionBuilder.Scan(joinEntity),
        (l, r) => DbExpressionBuilder.Equal(
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Property(l, "JoinId"),
                    DbExpressionBuilder.Property(r, "JoinId")
                )
    )
    .Select(exp => exp.Property("l"));
```

This will automatically generate query selecting all columns that "l" has.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @mr100.  I tried that initially and it throws the following error: 
`Invalid column name 'l'.
Invalid column name 'ResourceId'.
Invalid column name 'ResourceName'.
Invalid column name 'AccessId'.`
Not sure why it includes the 'l' as a column.  Also not sure why it thinks the other column names are invalid as well.

Comment: You probably messed up something somewhere else. I tried the code above and it works perfectly. I have an easy code sample on my machine that works with the above, I might sent it over to you if you would like to, so that you can compare it with your solution and see what is wrong.

Comment: Why do you need DbExpressionBuilder.And if you have in it only one equality comparison specifying the join condition?

Comment: Woops! Looks like I accidentally left off the second part of the .And condition. Just fixed it. I am also including the current userId in the join condition. I have tested the query this way in both SQL Server and when putting the anonymous projection and it definitely works. Is there anything about it that could be causing it to not recognize the column names when using `.Select(exp => exp.Property("l"))` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see the reason of that from your code. Could you post more details about the exception that you get. Post the line at which you obtain it, type of the Exception and stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you for your continued attention and responses @mr100.  I just edited my original post with more details.

Comment: But what kind of exception do you get with message "Invalid column name 'l'..."? Could you post some details?